# Access TFS Git Repository from Git GUI

Tags: git, tfs, msysgit

I have an on-premise TFS 2013.4 server hosting (besides other projects) a git repository.
The server is configured to use NTLM (but could be set to Kerberos as well).

Now I want to access that repository from a Windows Server, which has not and will not have Visual Studio (Full IDE) installed.

I tried using msys Git GUI, but can not successfully authenticate.
How can I clone the repository?

Version are:

- git-gui version 0.19.GITGUI
- git version 1.9.5.msysgit.1

Comment: Old Git versions didn't support NTLM. Which version are you using?

Comment: Just tried the command line interface - that knows how to do it - seems git gui is the culprit here!?

Comment: I use command line (1.8.3.msysgit.0) and SourceTree with no issues.